# Why are \r\n added to my string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, asp.net-mvc-3, stringwriter

**\r\n appearing on string?**

Attempting to use the example on [Rendering ASP.NET MVC Views to String](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/30/Rendering-ASPNET-MVC-Views-to-String) to pass a VIEW as a string, and send as an Email. Which should send the invoice of a sale through email to the user.

Iv'e added ViewRenderer class to my project. Then added the ContactSeller function to my controller, and copied and renamed the invoice view as ViewOrderThroughEmail.cshtml

```
//confirm payment & send invoice as email:
SendOrderInvoiceAsEmail(Qbcust, orderId);

private void SendOrderInvoiceAsEmail(QBCustomerRecord QBcust, int orderId)
{
    string email = QBcust.EmailAddress;
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(email))
    {
        _orchardServices.Notifier.Error(T("No E-mail exists for this user. Invoice not sent."));
        return;
    }

    var siteUrl = "Confirmation of order";

    if (_authenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUser() == null)
        throw new OrchardSecurityException(T("Login Required"));

    IUser userInfo = _authenticationService.GetAuthenticatedUser();

    QBCustomerRecord customer = _qbcustomerService.GetById(QBcust.Id);

    IEnumerable<OrderRecord> ordersQuery = _orderService.GetOrders(customer.Id);

    OrderRecord order = ordersQuery.Where(o => o.Id == orderId).FirstOrDefault();

    var ids = order.Details.Select(d => d.ProductId);

    ConvertOrderViewToStringViewModel model = new ConvertOrderViewToStringViewModel { Order = _orderService.GetOrder(orderId), Products = ProductHelper.GetProductLookup(ids, _qbProductService, true) };
    model.Order = _orderService.GetOrder(orderId);

    OrderSignatureRecord signatureRecord = _signatureService.GetByOrderId(orderId);
    if (signatureRecord != null)
    {
        model.PathToSignature = _mediaService.GetPublicUrl(signatureRecord.PathToImageFile);
                model.TypedName = signatureRecord.TypedName;
    }

    model.Payment = _paymentService.GetPaymentByOrderId(orderId);

    string orderInvoiceEmailAsString = ConvertViewToString(model);
    _userService.SendEmail(email, siteUrl, orderInvoiceEmailAsString);

    _orchardServices.Notifier.Information(T("The user will receive a confirmation of their order through email."));
}

public string ConvertViewToString(ConvertOrderViewToStringViewModel model)
{   
    string message = ViewRenderer.RenderView("~/Modules/StormTree/Views/Account/ViewOrderThroughEmail.cshtml",model, ControllerContext);

    return message;
}
```

I've gone through the sending email function, and I know from testing it that sending the email is not the problem. What the email contains is the problem.

```
public bool SendEmail(string usernameOrEmail, string title, string viewAsString)
{
    var lowerName = usernameOrEmail.ToLowerInvariant();
    var user = _contentManager.Query<UserPart, UserPartRecord>().Where(u => u.NormalizedUserName == lowerName || u.Email == lowerName).List().FirstOrDefault();

    if (user != null)
    {
        string nonce = CreateNonce(user, DelayToResetPassword);
        //string url = createUrl(nonce);
        string url = title;

        _messageManager.Send(user.ContentItem.Record, MessageTypes.LostPassword, "email", new Dictionary<string, string> { { "LostPasswordUrl", url } });
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

So I've breakpointed and checked the 'viewAsString' parameter passed in: returns:

```
"\r\n\r\n<div class=\"span6\">\r\n    <fieldset>\r\n        <h2 style=\"color:Red;\">Order details</h2>\r\n            <table style=\"border-bottom-color:Lime;\" class=\"table-bordered table-striped table\">\r\n                <colgroup>\r\n                    <col id=\"Col1\" />\r\n                    <col id=\"Col2\" />\r\n                    <col id=\"Col3\" />\r\n                    <col id=\"Col4\" />\r\n                    <col id=\"Col5\" />\r\n                </colgroup>\r\n                <thead>\r\n                    <tr>\r\n                        <th scope=\"col\">Code</th>\r\n                        <th scope=\"col\">Product</th>\r\n                        <th scope=\"col\">Unit Price</th>\r\n                        <th scope=\"col\">Quantity</th>\r\n                        <th scope=\"col\">Value</th>\r\n                    </tr>\r\n                </thead>\r\n                <tbody>\r\n                        <tr>\r\n                            <td>APPBRAMSI</td>\r\n                            <td>Single cooking apples</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                            <td>3</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                        </tr>\r\n                        <tr>\r\n                            <td>BUTTER SQ</td>\r\n                            <td>Butternut Squash</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                            <td>5</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                        </tr>\r\n                        <tr>\r\n                            <td>bcf5</td>\r\n                            <td>Broccolli &amp; Cauliflour Mix 5kg</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                            <td>2</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                        </tr>\r\n                        <tr>\r\n                            <td>EGGS TRAY</td>\r\n                            <td>tray eggs</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                            <td>1</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                        </tr>\r\n                        <tr>\r\n                            <td>savoy single</td>\r\n                            <td>Savoy Cabbage 1*</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                            <td>9</td>\r\n                            <td>&#163;0.00</td>\r\n                        </tr>\r\n                    <tr>\r\n                        <td></td>\r\n                        <td></td>\r\n                        <td></td>\r\n                        <td><strong>Sub-Total</strong></td>\r\n                        <td><strong>&#163;0.00</strong></td>\r\n                    </tr>\r\n                    <tr>\r\n                        <td></td>\r\n                        <td></td>\r\n                        <td></td>\r\n                        <td><strong>VAT</strong></td>\r\n                        <td><strong>&#163;0.00</strong></td>\r\n                    </tr>\r\n                    <tr>\r\n                        <td></td>\r\n                        <td></td>\r\n                        <td></td>\r\n                        <td><strong>Total</strong></td>\r\n                        <td><strong>&#163;0.00</strong></td>\r\n                    </tr>\r\n                </tbody>\r\n            </table>\r\n    </fieldset>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n<div class=\"span4\">\r\n    <fieldset>\r\n        <h2>Order information</h2>\r\n\r\n        <div class=\"editor-label\"><label for=\"Order_CreatedAt\">Order Last Updated</label></div>\r\n        <div class=\"editor-field\"><input class=\"uneditable-input\" id=\"Order_CreatedAt\" name=\"Order.CreatedAt\" readonly=\"readonly\" type=\"text\" value=\"19/12/2013 17:19:53\" /></div>\r\n\r\n        <div class=\"editor-label\"><label for=\"Order_Status\">Status</label></div>\r\n        <div class=\"editor-field\"><input class=\"uneditable-input\" id=\"Order_Status\" name=\"Order.Status\" readonly=\"readonly\" type=\"text\" value=\"New\" /></div>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n        <p><a href=\"/OrchardLocal/UMACS.Bradmount/CustomerAdmin/AddToCurrentOrder/171\" title=\"Add this order to Current Order\">Add this order to Current Order</a></p>\r\n        <p><a href=\"/OrchardLocal/UMACS.Bradmount/CustomerAdmin/ClearThenAddToCurrentOrder/171\" title=\"Change Current Order To Match This Order\">Change Current Order To Match This Order</a></p>\r\n        <p><a href=\"/OrchardLocal/UMACS.Bradmount/CustomerAdmin\" title=\"Back to My Account\">Go back to My Account</a></p>\r\n    </fieldset>\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n"
```

which displays:
[image]
My question being where are all the **\r\n** coming out of?
Thanks for any replies

**UPDATE**

```
public class ConvertOrderViewToStringViewModel
    {
        public ConvertOrderViewToStringViewModel()
        { }

        public OrderRecord Order;
        public Dictionary<int, QBProductRecord> Products;
        public String PathToSignature;
        public String TypedName;
        public PaymentRecord Payment;
    }
```

Comment: It looks like everything is getting escaped, notice the \" in the `Order Last Updated` as well as in your `title` parameter result. Try to see where the escaping occurs by debugging the code

Comment: Are you sure you checked the 'title' parameter & not 'viewAsString'? Because 'title' parameter is passed 'siteUrl' & 'siteUrl' is initialized with "Confirmation of Order" only. It is not changed after that. At least that is what I could see from your available code. I think the problem is with the 'viewAsString'.

Comment: These are new line characters, are you using enter key or new line to indent the report? Can you post code of ConvertOrderViewToStringViewModel constructor?

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi apologies you are correct. I have edited the OP

Comment: @nrathaus iv checked the ViewOrderThroughEmail.cshtml and there is no "\" or "n" or "r" ...i thought i might have made a type somewhere but nope seems ok. How can I see where the escaping occurs?

Comment: @PM. please see original post for ConvertOrderViewToStrigViewModel

Comment: You can see \r in the text and then \\r in the text, the first will appear as a single character, probably show up in hex 0x0d, the second will appear as a visible `\r` instead of a single character which cannot be displayed by the debugger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be its the white spaces that your view contains when formatted in visual studio.

So when you convert your `View` to `String` they get replaced by `\r\n` which represents white space & new line characters in `C#`.

You can try removing every white space from your view, which is not required. Have only html & relevant content in your view. Then test again by sending an email. See what happens.